# Unable to install Psutil

Tags: python, visual-c++, psutil

o/

I can't install Psutil package using :

> pip install psutil

I get the error message :
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required
Failed building wheel for psutil
Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject
.toml-based projects

I tried pretty much everything I found on other threads for the past 2 hours.

I uninstalled all older visual c++ versions and reinstalled the latest one (C++ 2015-2022)
Tried using older pip versions, tried --upgraded and ---v commands, and so on and so on, nothing works.

Any hints :) ?

Comment: Do you actually have the MS C++ *compiler*, or just the redistributable libraries?

Comment: Also, what version of Python are you using? There are pre-built wheels available for 2.7 and 3.6-3.10.

Comment: Just the library. I'm using Python 3.11

Comment: You need the actual compiler. You can install it for free, but's it's huge - at least a gig or two. Alternatively you can install [Python 3.10](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3108/) and you won't need to compile it yourself. As a second alternative, you can wait until they publish a wheel for 3.11.

Comment: Great it worked perfectly with Visual studio community 2022 compiler! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

fix on windows:

by installing Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio.

Select:  Workloads → Desktop development with C++.
Then for Individual Components, select only:

- "Windows SDK"
- "C++ x64/x86 build tools"

The build tools allow using MSVC “cl.exe” C / C++ compiler from the command line.

So `pip install psutil` is successfuly installed after that.